# Usage of SoftReference in Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, soft-references

I see below implementation of LRU cache in a legacy project where I have a question on usage of `SoftReference`
for value object but not for key object.

Here is the implementation

```
public class LRUCacheImpl<K, V> implements LRUCache<K, V> {

 // SoftReference is used for a memory friendly cache. 
 // The value will be removed under memory shortage situations and 
 // the keys of the values will be removed from the cache map. 
 private final Map<K, SoftReference<V>> cache;


 public LRUCacheImpl(final int cacheSize) {

  // 'true'  uses the access order instead of the insertion order.
  this.cache = new LinkedHashMap<K, SoftReference<V>> (cacheSize, 0.75f, true) {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, SoftReference<V>> eldest) {
    // When to remove the eldest entry i.e. Least Recently Used (i.e. LRU) entry
    return size() > cacheSize; // Size exceeded the max allowed.
   }
  };
 }

 @Override
 public V put(K key, V value) {
    SoftReference<V> previousValueReference = cache.put(key, new SoftReference<V>(value));
    return previousValueReference != null ? previousValueReference.get() : null;
 }

 @Override
 public V get(K key) {
     SoftReference<V> valueReference = cache.get(key);
     return valueReference != null ? valueReference.get() : null;
 }
}
```

GC reclaims the memory for softly reachable objects if application is about to reach OutOfMemory(OOM).
 If I apply the same logic, only memory for value should be reclaimed (as soft reference is created for value object only).
 But here is the comment in the beginning of file

> ```
> // SoftReference is used for a memory friendly cache.
> // The value will be removed under memory shortage situations and
> // the keys of the values will be removed from the cache map.
> ```

My question is how corresponding key object will be removed from map once app reach OOM. Should not the key be wrapped
 with soft reference as well?

```
cache.put(new SoftReference<K>(key), new SoftReference<V>(value));
```

Comment: `Key` expects to be smaller in size compare to Value, So making key as soft ref does not really help much

Comment: Is the code you posted the complete class? The `removeEldestEntry` method implies that the number of keys in this map should be limited to `cacheSize`, but I don't see it enforced anywhere.

Comment: @Eran This is complete code. removeEldestEntry is called internally while put operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the fact the `LinkedHashMap` supports limiting the size of the map. By implementing `removeEldestEntry`, you prevent the map from holding more than `cacheSize` keys.

As you can see in the `LinkedHashMap` implementation, adding a new Entry causes the removal of the eldest entry if `removeEldestEntry` returns true.

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    createEntry(hash, key, value, bucketIndex);

    // Remove eldest entry if instructed, else grow capacity if appropriate
    Entry<K,V> eldest = header.after;
    if (removeEldestEntry(eldest)) {
        removeEntryForKey(eldest.key);
    } else {
        if (size >= threshold)
            resize(2 * table.length);
    }
}
```

Therefore, the least recently used keys would be removed from the map.

Using this constructor :

```
this.cache = new LinkedHashMap<K, SoftReference<V>> (cacheSize, 0.75f, true)
```

means that the entries are ordered according to their access order. Therefore, each time you get or put a key, you move the corresponding entry to the back of the list linked list, which meant the start of the list contains the least recently used Entry.

Therefore, the `//the keys of the values will be removed from the cache map` probably refers to the fact that the least recently used keys would eventually be removed from the map, independently of the removal of values under memory shortage.

Comment: sorry for late comment. But my question here is `Should not the key be wrapped with soft reference as well?` instead of just values in case out of memory occurs so that key and values both are removed ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping keys in `Reference`s is an option, if intricate.
The goal is to avoid OOM while not incurring whatever drawback there is to not getting values from the cache for letting go of them needlessly.
Just wrapping keys in `Reference`s isn't enough with standard Map implementations -
without overriding `equals()`&`hashCode()`, no keys would appear equal: nothing gets found, replaced, removed, …
Another approach is to use `Soft/WeakReference`s with the `Map.Entry`s: see `java.util.WeakHashMap<K, V>` for an example of how to do it (with Reference to the key, incidentally). The advantage is that you can get rid of any remaining strong references once you notice the soft/weak one is gone.
Then, there is [trove4j](https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove), [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/index.html), [Goldman Sachs](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/blob/master/README.md)…